# Необходимо построить 3D график в проекции 2D (Python)

Tags: python

Есть набор из 100 измерений (допустим, средний ток от частоты изменения напряжения, не важно). И каждое из этих измерений отличается доп. параметром. Я хочу построить трехмерный график в виде графика интенсивности (двумерная проекция) (X - частота, Y - дополнительный параметр, Z - средний ток). Величина Z должна различаться цветом.

Я пробовал использовать библиотеку matplotlib, но все примеры, что я нашел, имеют строгую математическую зависимость от [X,Y].

Жду вашего совета, как мне реализовать данный замысел. Спасибо!

Comment: Проблема в 3д графике? https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html

Comment: Проблема представить это в двухмере.

Comment: @Виктор на бумаге сможете нарисовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то можно сделать так:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
y = [1,4,2,2,5,1,7,8,5]
z = [5,5,2,3,6,7,1,3,3]

plt.scatter(x, y, c=z, s=100, cmap='Reds') # c задает цветность, в зависимости от z
plt.colorbar()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо! Да, именно это и необходимо было!

Comment: @Виктор, чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, [отметьте его как решение](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)